# How to remove particular value in array_map in php

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist, yii2-advanced-app, array-map

Here below my array_map example,

```
$page_names = ArrayHelper::map($pagesList['data'], 'id', 'name');
```

Here below my array_map output,

```
Array
(
[2042793285968] => YoungZen Technologies
[777607709013] => Challengers
[772593172886] => Vadavalli
[152429224945] => Time Pass
)
```

now i want to remove 'Challengers' in the above list and i have to use the same $page_names variable for dropdown list without challengers.

I am not good in array concept, I tried like array_filter and in_array that is not happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one option:

```
unset($page_names[array_search('Challengers', $page_names)]);
```

To break down the logic here, first we call `array_search` with the *value* you want to identify in your associate array.  `array_search` will return the first key corresponding to this value, if the value can be found.

Then, we use `unset` passing in the corresponding key, to completely remove that key/value pair from the array.

To remove an entry from the map using the key, the code is much simpler:

```
unset($page_names[777607709013]);
```

Comment: Hey!, thanks man that's working. what should I do if I want to check with the key like unset($page_names[array_search('777607709013', $page_names)]); this is not working

Comment: @sridhar You may just use `unset($page_names[777607709013])` ... the code is much simpler for this.

Comment: yeah its working thank you so much, but we have to use within single quotes like  unset($page_names['2042793285968339']); please update in your answer

Comment: @sridhar For integer keys, I don't think you need to use quotes.  If those id's are actually strings (which appears to be the case), then yes, you'd need to use quotes.

Answer (score 2):

solution using the array_diff

```
$page_names = array_diff($page_names, ['Challengers']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can filter it out -

```
$arr = array_filter($arr, function($v) {
    return $v != 'Challengers'; // return true if value not 'Cha...'
});
```

[array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

Comment: This is also working thank you, dude. both answers are working. also please let me know what should I do the same thing with key value like return $v != '777607709013' this

Comment: `ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY` as third parameter. It will pass the key. Check the link I have added to the answer.